# Change edge target in boost graph

Tags: boost

Assume I have a simple graph with three vertices, How could I change output edge of 0 to 2 instead of 1

[image]

Note: I don't want to do it while creating the graph.

Comment: What is your simple graph? `m_target` is not something that "exists" in Boost Graph (it's not part of the public interface)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the simple graph that you left out of the question:

```
auto simple_graph() {
    boost::adjacency_list<> g;
    add_edge(0, 1, g);
    add_edge(1, 2, g);
    return g;
}
```

Now the absolute simplest you can do [*for this graph model*](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/graph/doc/graph_concepts.html) is

```
// change (0,1) to (0,2):
remove_edge(0, 1, g);
add_edge(0, 2, g);
```

### Demo

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/53rz3hnPM)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

auto simple_graph() {
    boost::adjacency_list<> g;
    add_edge(0, 1, g);
    add_edge(1, 2, g);
    return g;
}

int main() {
    auto g = simple_graph();
    write_graphviz(std::cout, g);

    // change (0,1) to (0,2):
    remove_edge(0, 1, g);
    add_edge(0, 2, g);

    write_graphviz(std::cout, g);
}
```

Prints

```
digraph G {
0;
1;
2;
0->1 ;
1->2 ;
}
digraph G {
0;
1;
2;
0->2 ;
1->2 ;
}
```

So indeed [image] becomes
[image]

### Other Graph Types

In case you had other graph types, other approaches become natural:

**[Live: edge list](https://godbolt.org/z/8d4drv1Mr)**

```
#include <boost/graph/edge_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

int main() {
    std::vector edges{std::pair{0, 1}, {1, 2}};
    boost::edge_list g(edges.begin(), edges.end());

    // change (0,1) to (0,2):
    edges[0].second = 2;
}
```

### UPDATE: Bonus Preserving Properties

I'd write a 5-line helper function:

```
template <typename V, typename G>
void update_edge_target(V source, V target, V new_target, G& g) {
    if (auto [e, exists] = edge(source, target, g); exists) {
        auto prop = std::move(g[e]);
        remove_edge(e, g);
        add_edge(source, new_target, prop, g);
    }
}
```

> Note: I don't think BGL supports move semantics, so splitting the last
> line could improve efficiency:
>
> ```
>     e = add_edge(source, new_target, g);
>     g[e] = std::move(prop);
> ```

See it **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/z1x6zb37n)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

struct EdgeProps {
    std::map<int, std::string> lots;
    std::string more;
};

auto simple_graph() {
    using namespace boost;
    adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS, no_property, EdgeProps> g;
    add_edge(0, 1,
            {{
                {1, "one"},
                {2, "two"},
                {3, "three"},
            },
            "very heavy data!"},
            g);
    add_edge(1, 2,
            {{
                {4, "four"},
                {5, "five"},
                {6, "size"},
            },
            "needs preserving"},
            g);
    return g;
}

template <typename V, typename G>
void update_edge_target(V source, V target, V new_target, G& g) {
    if (auto [e, exists] = edge(source, target, g); exists) {
        auto prop = std::move(g[e]);
        remove_edge(e, g);
        add_edge(source, new_target, prop, g);
    }
}

// for debug output
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
template <typename G> struct writer : boost::default_writer {
    G const& g;
    explicit writer(G const& g) : g(g) {}

    void operator()(std::ostream& os, auto const& desc) const { handle(os, g[desc]); }

private:
    void handle(std::ostream& os, boost::no_property) const { os << "[]"; }
    void handle(std::ostream& os, EdgeProps const& ep) const {
        os << "[label=" << boost::escape_dot_string(ep.more)
        << ",extra=" << boost::escape_dot_string(fmt::format("{}", ep.lots))
        << "]";
    }
};

int main() {
    auto g = simple_graph();

    writer w{g};
    write_graphviz(std::cout, g, w, w);

    // change (0,1) to (0,2):
    update_edge_target(0, 1, 2, g);

    write_graphviz(std::cout, g, w, w);
}
```

Prints

```
digraph G {
0[];
1[];
2[];
0->1 [label="very heavy data!",extra="{1: \"one\", 2: \"two\", 3: \"three\"}"];
1->2 [label="needs preserving",extra="{4: \"four\", 5: \"five\", 6: \"size\"}"];
}
digraph G {
0[];
1[];
2[];
0->2 [label="very heavy data!",extra="{1: \"one\", 2: \"two\", 3: \"three\"}"];
1->2 [label="needs preserving",extra="{4: \"four\", 5: \"five\", 6: \"size\"}"];
}
```

Which renders:
[image] to
[image]

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in my question. there are some properties associated with the edge, I don't want to remove and add a new edge. Instead, point the m_target of that edge to a new vertex.

Comment: As you can see, that's not a possibility for all graph models.

Comment: I've added an update showing how to preserve properties generically.